# It is possible to code `if(($(document).onmouseup) && (value_ == 1))`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yesterday i asked the [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935873/when-calling-raphael-function-jquerys-draggable-and-resizable-not-working?noredirect=1#comment49938369_30935873)  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4skeuhu3/7/)

My problem is, values are passing to the function in every mouse up event So dragging and resizeable was not correcty working.

so i write something like

```
var value_ = 1;
div_mainscale.onmousedown = function(event) {
    var mouseCoords = getCoords(event);
    startX = mouseCoords.x - offset[0];
    startY =1 ;//mouseCoords.y - offset[1];
    rect = mainscale.rect(startX, startY);
    document.onmousemove = doDraw;
    rect.attr({fill: 'rgba(255, 6, 6, 0.41)', stroke: 'red'}); 
    value_ = 1;
};
if(($(document).onmouseup) && (value_ == 1)) // here i make mistake
{
    selectable_area(width,startX);
    rect.remove();
}
```

instead of this code

```
document.onmouseup = function() {
if(rect)
{
    selectable_area(width,startX);
    rect.remove();
}

document.onmousemove = null;
};
```

But `if(($(document).onmouseup) && (value_ == 1))` this condition was not satisfied? How can i fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("mouseup" , function(e) {
    if (value_ == 1) {
        value_ = 0;
        selectable_area(width,startX);
        rect.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: It is also give same result.

Comment: You weren't resetting value_ anywhere. Is that the cause of your issue? Example updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (value_ == 1) {
        selectable_area(width, startX);
        rect.remove();
    }
});
```

Try above code its working for me